# How do I create a Linked List Data Structure in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

What's the best way to make a linked list in Java?

Comment: The best way to make a linked list is to use the built in linked list. Don't re-write built in classes.

Comment: this question is legitimate and very constructive for programmers discussion

Answer (score 220, accepted):

The obvious solution to developers familiar to Java is to use the **LinkedList** class already provided in **java.util**. Say, however, you wanted to make your own implementation for some reason. Here is a quick example of a linked list that inserts a new link at the beginning of the list, deletes from the beginning of the list and loops through the list to print the links contained in it. **Enhancements** to this implementation include making it a **double-linked list**, adding methods to **insert** and **delete** from the middle or end, and by adding **get** and **sort** methods as well.

**Note**: In the example, the Link object doesn't actually contain another Link object -  *nextLink* is actually only a reference to another link.

```
class Link {
    public int data1;
    public double data2;
    public Link nextLink;

    //Link constructor
    public Link(int d1, double d2) {
        data1 = d1;
        data2 = d2;
    }

    //Print Link data
    public void printLink() {
        System.out.print("{" + data1 + ", " + data2 + "} ");
    }
}

class LinkList {
    private Link first;

    //LinkList constructor
    public LinkList() {
        first = null;
    }

    //Returns true if list is empty
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return first == null;
    }

    //Inserts a new Link at the first of the list
    public void insert(int d1, double d2) {
        Link link = new Link(d1, d2);
        link.nextLink = first;
        first = link;
    }

    //Deletes the link at the first of the list
    public Link delete() {
        Link temp = first;
        if(first == null){
         return null;
         //throw new NoSuchElementException(); // this is the better way. 
        }
        first = first.nextLink;
        return temp;
    }

    //Prints list data
    public void printList() {
        Link currentLink = first;
        System.out.print("List: ");
        while(currentLink != null) {
            currentLink.printLink();
            currentLink = currentLink.nextLink;
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}  

class LinkListTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkList list = new LinkList();

        list.insert(1, 1.01);
        list.insert(2, 2.02);
        list.insert(3, 3.03);
        list.insert(4, 4.04);
        list.insert(5, 5.05);

        list.printList();

        while(!list.isEmpty()) {
            Link deletedLink = list.delete();
            System.out.print("deleted: ");
            deletedLink.printLink();
            System.out.println("");
        }
        list.printList();
    }
}
```

Comment: you could also quite easily improve this code to use generics for the data type rather than storing an int and a double.

Comment: @shsteimer: quite definitely, but since pretty much the only good use of this code is to demonstrate the technique, it wouldn't help anyone. It would only diffuse the basic idea.

Comment: It isn't good OO approach to have `public Link nextLink` and operating on it outside the class. It could be respectable when `Link` would be an internal class of `LinkList`. It is another bunch of code written as Java was only another-version-of-c.

Comment: When you Insert, your first item will never get a nextLink - unless I'm missing something with Java references

Comment: How can I implement delete(index)  method?

Comment: If you delete from an empty list, you'll get a NullPointerException, specifically when you try to access `first.nextLink`

Answer (score 55):

Java has a [LinkedList](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) implementation, that you might wanna check out. You can download the JDK and it's sources at [java.sun.com](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp).

Comment: Does Java's Linkedlist doesn't allow you insert and remove elements at arbitrary positions?

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of a linked list?

Comment: @Seun Osewa if you want to add at an arbitrary position pls use an ArrayList :)

Comment: Instead of downloading the JDK to view its implementation of `LinkedList`, you can just [view its `LinkedList.java` online here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/LinkedList.java). That page even syntax-highlights the code and renders the Javadoc comments inline.

Answer (score 22):

Use [java.util.LinkedList](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html). Like this:

```
list = new java.util.LinkedList()
```

Answer (score 18):

The above linked list display in opposite direction. I think the correct implementation of insert method should be

```
public void insert(int d1, double d2) { 
    Link link = new Link(d1, d2); 

    if(first==null){
        link.nextLink = null;
        first = link; 
        last=link;
    }
    else{
        last.nextLink=link;
        link.nextLink=null;
        last=link;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add new at end unless otherwise stated. :-)

Answer (score 10):

Its much better to use java.util.LinkedList, because it's probably much more optimized, than the one that you will write.

Comment: And it will work first time.

Answer (score 7):

```
//slightly improved code without using collection framework

package com.test;

public class TestClass {

    private static Link last;
    private static Link first;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Inserting
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            Link.insert(i+5);
        }
        Link.printList();

        //Deleting
        Link.deletefromFirst();
        Link.printList();
    }


    protected  static class Link {
        private int data;
        private Link nextlink;

        public Link(int d1) {
            this.data = d1;
        }

        public static void insert(int d1) {
            Link a = new Link(d1);
            a.nextlink = null;
            if (first != null) {
                last.nextlink = a;
                last = a;
            } else {
                first = a;
                last = a;
            }
            System.out.println("Inserted -:"+d1);
        }

        public static void deletefromFirst() {
            if(null!=first)
            {
                System.out.println("Deleting -:"+first.data);
                first = first.nextlink;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("No elements in Linked List");
            }
        }

        public static void printList() {
            System.out.println("Elements in the list are");
            System.out.println("-------------------------");
            Link temp = first;
            while (temp != null) {
                System.out.println(temp.data);
                temp = temp.nextlink;
            }
        }
    }
}
```