# help with lists?

Tags: java, data-structures, list

im learning linked lists in java but am stuck on the following

**Before deleting Hobnobs: bourbon, shortbread, Hobnobs, oreos**

**After deleting Hobnobs: bourbon, shortbread, oreos**

i would like to create a delete method that will delete the intermediate node "Hobnobs".

ive got this so far

```
 public class Biscuit {

 private BiscuitNode first;
 public Biscuit( )
 {
  this.first=null;
 }
 public BiscuitNode getFirst() {
  return first;
 }
 public void insert(BiscuitNode first) {
  this.first = first;
 }

 public void deleteFirst()
 {
  this.first.setSucc(this.first);
 }

 public void delete(String BiscuitName)
 {
```

the Hobnobs is "`BiscuitNode secondLast=new BiscuitNode("Hobnobs", last);`"

Comment: It sounds like this is a homework question. Nothing wrong with asking homework questions on SO but you should tag them as "homework."

In real life, though, you should typically use the built-in `java.util.LinkedList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walk the chain of nodes in a loop using getSucc() on the current node. Then, once you find the node that matches, make its predecessor point to its successor. E.g. if we want to delete node C from the following list:

```
A--->B--->C--->D

becomes

A--->B--->D
```

You should be able to figure it out.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042/how-do-i-implement-a-linked-list-in-java.

Answer (score 1):

Add a recursive method to `BiscuitNode`, maybe named `deleteYourSuccessorIfItMatches(String pattern)` that checks if it's successor matches the pattern and if it does, the successor of the current node would be set to the successor of the successor, else the method is called recursively on the successor. The calling method, `Biscuit.delete(String pattern)` has to do the same thing on the `first` node.