# Can anyone would provide me an example of reference-based linked list?

Tags: java, reference, linked-list, pseudocode

I'm trying to create a reference based linked list anyone would be able to provide me an example of it??

Comment: See [How do I implement a Linked List in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042/how-do-i-implement-a-linked-list-in-java).  In Java, all linked lists are reference-based.

Comment: @Gabriel Yes it is a homework indeed....
@Matthew Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Double or simple link? This shouldn't be too hard to do by yourself. What you need is an element class to form a basic container with one reference to an Object and other references that can be used for linking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an answer as such but the following domain class should get you started:

```
public class Element{

private Object objectLink;

private Element nextElement;
private Element previousElement;

// Getter and setter methods here

}
```

What you need to add to this is a class that allows adding, removal and checking the state of the list (empty, size, etc.).

Comment: I've created a linked list with this.
public LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
Does it still require heads or iterator sort of things in order to create a linked list??

Comment: Well, it depends on whether you are required to implement the full List interface http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html or if what is asked is to create something that fits this description http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list