# How to reverse LinkedList in java

Tags: java

Please accept my apologies first, but I could not reverse my Linked List in java..

I have class and inner class:

```
MyList{

class Element{
private Element next;

public Element getNext(){return next;}
}

 public void reverseMyList(Element curr) {

        if (curr.next == null) {
            head = curr.next;
            return;
        }
        reverseMyList(curr.next);
        while (curr.next != null) {
            curr.next.next = curr.next;
            curr.next = null;
        }
}//:~
```

I need to reverse my List, I am using method reverseMyList, which needs Element curr.
If my way of thinking in this case is correct ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there supposed to be something *in* these lists? I don't see anywhere to put elements.

Comment: is recursion mandatory ? homework ?

Comment: If this is for homework, you may find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354875/reversing-a-linked-list-in-java-recursively or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943720/reversing-a-singly-linked-list-iteratively useful.

Comment: If you need a hint, you don't need any recursive calls to reverse your list.  You just iterate over your list, and make sure that each element's `next` points back to what use to be it's parent

Comment: What is `head` your example is not correct. Even your `Element` is wrong

Comment: A linked list doesn't really have a predefined order. It is just the convention to follow the chain in a specific direction (by accessing `Node.next`). However, you could simply walk in the other direction (since it is a loop).

Answer (score 0):

Since this kinda looks like homework, I'm not going to lay out the entire solution here, but I will explain how you should conceptually do it.

Imagine that you have 2 linked lists.  You have your input list that you need to reverse, and you have an empty one.

If you keep taking the **first** element off of the original list, and keep putting that on the **front** of the new list until your original list is empty, than your new list will be what the original was, except reversed.

Comment: Pushing everything into a stack and then popping into a new list would also work. Implementation left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Reverse(Element element)
    {
        Element current = element;
        Element next = current.Next;
        Element nextToNext;

        var first = current;

        while (next != null && next.Next != null)
        {
            nextToNext = next.Next;

            next.Next = current;

            current = next;

            next = nextToNext;
        }

        if (next != null)
        {
            next.Next = current;
        }

        first.Next = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the method you are looking for **already exist in package `java.utils`**:

```
Collections.reverse(mylist);
```

this method will change the order of element direcly inside your list and **you dont need to instance a new list-object**... [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-reverse-java-examples/) you can find more specified documentation