# Nodes in Java, coming from C background

Tags: java, c, linked-list, nodes

A while ago I implemented a LinkedList in C. It was pretty straight forward since each Node was made of a value and another pointer to the next element in the list. But now I am trying to implement a LinkedList in Java, since there are no pointer I made a Node like this:

```
public class MyNode{
    int value;
    MyNode next;

    public MyNode(int i){
        value = i;
        next = null;
    }
}
```

Now lets say I have this:

```
MyNode n1 = new MyNode(1);
MyNode n2 = new MyNode(2);
n1.next = n2;
MyNode n3 = new MyNode(3);
n2 = n3;
```

What would I get if I do

```
System.println(n1.next.value);
```

Would I get a 2 or a 3? My main problem coming from C is that I do not really understand how java moves around the data. Does it copy n2 to n1 or does n1 just point to n2? This is all really confusing.

Comment: *Would I get a 2 or a 3?* => Why don't you try?

Comment: You are completely right. I should have tried it before I asked, still I would like to know how Java handles the line "n1.next = n2;"

Comment: This might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042/how-do-i-implement-a-linked-list-in-java

Comment: @Hiny please **read** the question at the bottom of OP body.

Comment: This and related questions are very well explained in Java tutorials. See [StackOverflow Java wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) to get a Java introduction and a list of available online tutorials on the net.

Comment: Java has LinkedList builtin so I assume this is just an exercise.  It might be worth reading the source of how Java does it as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To try to make an analogy with pointers (we call them references in Java):

You can think of variables (n1, n2, n1.next etc.) as pointers to objects somewhere in memory. So `new Node(2);` creates a Node and places it in memory and `n2 = ...` makes the variable `n2` point to the "address" of that node.

When you then write `n1.next = n2;`, you make `n1.next` point to that same "address" by copying the **value** of that address into `n1.next`.

When you later write `n2 = n3;`, you make the `n2` variable point to a different "address", but `n1.next` is still pointing to the address of your initial `new Node(2)` object.

Bottom line: `System.out.println(n1.next.value);` prints 2, not 3.

A related post: [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Comment: At last a decent answer that do not talk about *Java passes by reference*.

Answer (score 1):

The response is 2.

**n1.next** will continue to point to your instance *MyNode(2);*
After **n2 = n3;** n2 points to the n3 but you will keep a reference for the instance *MyNode(2)* on **n1.next**.

The GarbageCollector only will collect the objects instances that don't have any references to them. In this case you will continue to reference the instance (MyNode(2)) on **n1.next**

Answer (score 0):

In java the variables are always passed by values. Java passes objects as references passed by value.

For example, your code

```
MyNode n1 = new MyNode(1);
MyNode n2 = new MyNode(2);
n1.next = n2;
MyNode n3 = new MyNode(3);
n2 = n3;
```

Is executed in this way.

> Create new node as n1 with value 1
>
> create new node as n2 with value 2
>
> Set the object n1.next to n2
>
> Create new node as n3 with value 3
>
> Replace object referenced by n2 with the one referenced by n3 (It doesn't replace the reference of `n1.next`

So your call for

```
System.out.println(n1.next.value);
```

prints 2.

Comment: *My main problem coming from C is that I do not really understand how java moves around the data. Does it copy n2 to n1 or does n1 just point to n2? This is all really confusing.* This is the real problem.

Comment: AFAIK an `int` is not a reference, just a primitive type. Is an `int` variable passed as reference as well: *In java the variables are passed by references*?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza *But the variables of data types are passed by values.*

Comment: Please see the link about Java is pass by reference in [assylias' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16029415/1065197) and get your own conclusion about it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks. Learnt a new thing today.

Comment: Don't worry. By the way, if you learned it well, please edit your answer (and maybe I will remove my downvote)

Comment: Still has no good sense. Please refer (one more time) to assylias's answer, read it and try to explain this in human language (note that you have *Call n1.next returns n2* and later *because n2 is replaced by n3 but 'next' isn't changed* sounds kinda tangled isn't?).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Is it well now?

Comment: Yes it is now. Good to know you learned two things: Java pass by value and explain your ideas thinking in how people will understand you.