# Stuck with a nullpointerexception on linked list implementation

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, nodes

When trying to add things at a specific index to my linkedlist, I am receiving a nullpointerexception. I know *why*, but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is my code for the nodes of the linked list

```
public class LinkedList<Key> implements LinkedListInterface<Key>{
        private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    private int size = 0;

    private class Node{
        Key key;
        Node next;
    }
```

And here is my code where I'm trying to add to the linked list at a specific index.

```
 public void add(int index, Key key) {
        if(index < size){
        Node left = null, newNode = null;
        Node right = head;
        for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){
            left = right;
            right = right.next;
        }
        left.next = newNode;
        newNode.next = right;
        newNode.key = key;
        size++;
        }
        else{
            addToEnd(key);
        }
    }
private void addToEnd(Key key) {
        Node lastNode = new Node();
        if(size == 0){
            tail = head = lastNode;
        }
        else{
            lastNode.key = key;
            tail.next = lastNode;
            tail = lastNode;
        }
        size++;     
    }
```

I know that by default my nodes will be null, but I am unable to do anything with them until they have a value. However, it seems that in order to be able to assign a value to them, they can't be null. I just can't wrap my head around it.

Thanks for the help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21632621/add-nodes-in-linked-list/21633256#21633256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding a node, you need memory allocated for the new node.

So, when you create newNode, allocate memory for it:

```
Node left = null, newNode = new Node();
```

Comment: Are you free to skype for a few minutes? I'm experiencing a really weird bug when debugging and I don't even know how to describe it without sharing my screen.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you just need to initialize `newNode` up there on the second line of `add(...)`, rather than setting the variable to null.