# Polynomial Linked List does not return the list

Tags: java

this is my first time asking in here. I am creating a Polynomial using Linked List in java.

I'm trying to convert a string of polynomial to nodes in linked list and do addition and subtraction.

I create a method that split polynomial to terms and store it in linked list. I tried to print out the list inside that method, and it works. However, when I want to print the list using toString method or call add or subtract method, it says that my list is null. Can someone help me, and explain it to me why the list go to null?

This is my Term class

```
public class Term 
{
   int coef;
   int exp;
   Term next;

public Term()
{
    coef = 0;
    exp = 0;
    next = null;
}

public Term(int coef, int exp)
{
    this.coef = coef;
    this.exp = exp;
    this.next = null;
}

public void setCoef(int coef)
{
    this.coef = coef;
}

public void setExp(int exp)
{
    this.exp = exp;
}

public int getCoef()
{
    return coef;
}

public int getExp()
{
    return exp;
}

public void setNext(Term next)
{
    this.next = next;
}

public Term getNext()
{
    return next;
}

public String toString() 
{
    String str = "";

    if (exp == 0)
    {
        if (coef < 0)
            str += coef;
        else
            str += "+" + coef;
    }
    else if (exp == 1)
    {
        if (coef < 0)
            str += coef + "x";
        else
            str += "+" + coef + "x";
    }
    else if (coef < 0)
        str += coef + "x^" + exp;
    else
        str += "+" + coef + "x^" + exp;

    return str;
}
}
```

My LinkedListPolynomial class

```
public class LinkedListPolynomial implements PolynomialInterface 
{
int coefficient, exponent;
private Term head;

public LinkedListPolynomial() 
{
    head = null;
}

public LinkedListPolynomial(int coefficient, int exponent) 
{
    this.coefficient = coefficient;
    this.exponent = exponent;
    head = new Term(coefficient, exponent);
}

public LinkedListPolynomial(String n) 
{
    String s1New = n.replaceAll("-", "+-");
    String[] arr = s1New.split("\\+");

            //if the first term contains negative coefficient, the first term is empty
    if (arr[0].isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i].contains("x^")) 
            {
                String str = arr[i].substring(0, arr[i].indexOf("x^"));
                String poly = arr[i].substring(arr[i].indexOf("x^") + 2);

                coefficient = Integer.parseInt(str);
                exponent = Integer.parseInt(poly);

                if (head == null) 
                {
                    head = new Term(coefficient, exponent);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    Term newNode = new Term(coefficient, exponent);
                    newNode.setNext(head);
                    head = newNode;
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                coefficient = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
                exponent = 0;

                if (head == null) 
                {
                    head = new Term(coefficient, exponent);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    Term newNode = new Term(coefficient, exponent);
                    newNode.setNext(head);
                    head = newNode;
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
        {
            if (arr[i].contains("x^"))
            {
                String str = arr[i].substring(0, arr[i].indexOf("x^"));
                String poly = arr[i].substring(arr[i].indexOf("x^") + 2);

                coefficient = Integer.parseInt(str);
                exponent = Integer.parseInt(poly);

                if (head == null) 
                {
                    head = new Term(coefficient, exponent);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    Term newNode = new Term(coefficient, exponent);
                    newNode.setNext(head);
                    head = newNode;
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                coefficient = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
                exponent = 0;

                if (head == null) 
                {
                    head = new Term(coefficient, exponent);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    Term newNode = new Term(coefficient, exponent);
                    newNode.setNext(head);
                    head = newNode;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    selectionSort();

    int i = 0;
    while (head != null) 
    {
        System.out.print(head);
        head = head.getNext();
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("\n");

}

public PolynomialInterface add(PolynomialInterface other)
{
    LinkedListPolynomial sum = new LinkedListPolynomial();
    LinkedListPolynomial parameter = (LinkedListPolynomial) other;

    return sum;
}

public PolynomialInterface subtract(PolynomialInterface other)
{
    LinkedListPolynomial subtract = new LinkedListPolynomial();
    LinkedListPolynomial parameter = (LinkedListPolynomial) other;

    return subtract;
}

public String toString()
{
    String str = "";
    Term current = head;

    if (current == null)
        str += "it's null";
    else
    {
        while (current.getNext() != null) { current = current.getNext(); 
        str += current.getCoef() + "x^" + current.getExp(); }
    }

    return str;

}

public void selectionSort() 
{
    for (Term node1 = head; node1 != null; node1 = node1.getNext()) // number of iterations
    {
        Term min = node1;// assumes min node is the node under
                            // considerations
        // selects the min node
        for (Term node2 = node1; node2 != null; node2 = node2.getNext()) 
        {
            if (min.getExp() < node2.getExp()) 
            {
                min = node2;
            }

        }
        // swaps the min node with the node in its actual position
        Term temp = new Term(node1.getCoef(), node1.getExp());
        node1.coef = min.getCoef();
        node1.exp = min.getExp();
        min.coef = temp.getCoef();
        min.exp = temp.getExp();
    }
}
}
```

My PolynomialInterface

```
public interface PolynomialInterface 
{
PolynomialInterface add(PolynomialInterface other);
PolynomialInterface subtract(PolynomialInterface other);
String toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `add` and `subtract` methods you are creating your list using the default constructor, which sets its `head` to `null` and does nothing else, then returning that empty list. You'll need to actually implement the functionality of `add` and `subtract`. See [How do I implement a Linked List in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042/how-do-i-implement-a-linked-list-in-java) for a decent primer.

Comment: Could you explain it more about returning the `other` list in each method? How can I return it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read enough of the methods when I replied and wrote that second sentence. Edited my answer.